# How to edit Resources file (.resx ) after publishing in Blazor Server Project?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a Blazor Server Project in which I want to add a feature to Edit resource files after publishing. Exactly after publishing, there would be a publish folder in the bin directory of the project. I need to edit the string in the resources file contains in the bin directory.

Expected behavior: able to edit .resx file after publishing blazor server project.

Comment: Welcome. Why do you want to do this? To do this, you need access and changes in the executable folder of the application on the server, which can create a serious security vulnerability for your application.

Comment: @AlirezaK, using the **CopyToOutputDirectory** property, I just want to add a particular .resx file in publish folder so that I can change any value inside the file and it would reflect on the webpage after reloading it without republishing. I am sure that it would not create security vulnerability for the application.

Comment: You can't. The files are changed to C# code in the build process using t4.